# Fetch a CKReference object from a CKReference

Tags: ios, database, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckreference

I have 3 records types which contained attributes like this :

### Client

> Username : String
>
> ProfilImage : UIImage

### Comment

> User : Client Reference
>
> Message : String

### Shop

> Comments : Comment Reference List

Can I fetch the client Username and ProfilImage from a Shop CKRecord object ? Can I do this path :

1. Fetch the comments references from a Record of Shop
2. Fetch the user reference from each comment reference found
3. And finally fetch the username and profil from the user reference of comment reference of shop record

If there's a path, what's the best way to do this ?

Comment: Your list of steps is correct. As for actually doing that, it's no different than doing any other fetch.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer @rmaddy. I need to be sure that these steps are good before doing a lot of stuff…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example for Step 1. The other steps would follow similarly from the steps you've listed, cascading on the results of each previous step.  (NOTE: There is no need for the explicit CKReference fields since they can be gleaned from the CKRecord variables, but I wanted to make the example more readable)

```
struct Shop {
  // other variables....
  var record : CKRecord?
  var commentRef : CKReference?
}

struct Comment {
  // other variables....
  var record : CKRecord?
  var clientRef : CKReference?
}

var shops : [Shop]
var comments : [Comment]

func commentsWithReference(ref: CKReference) -> [Comment] {
  let matchingComments = comments.filter {$0.record!.recordID == ref.recordID }
  return matchingComments
}

let shopComments = shops.map { commentsWithReference($0.commentRef!) }
```

Comment: Thank you, tha's exactly what I was looking for ;)